# Can not connect to redis-cluster in remote server with spring webflux project

Tags: java, spring-webflux, remote-server, redis-cluster

firs sorry about my English .
i have a spring webFlux project , i want to connect redis-cluster in remote server. i just run redis-cluster with docker-compose . everything is ok . i have telnet from my pc to remote server in cluster ports . but when i run my project , throws excpetion that can not connect to remote  . can anyone help me ?

my config :

```
@Bean
    @Primary
    public LettuceConnectionFactory  reactiveRedisConnectionFactory(RedisClusterConfiguration defaultRedisConfig) {
        LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
                .readFrom(ReadFrom.ANY)
                .commandTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(60000)).build();
     return   new  LettuceConnectionFactory(defaultRedisConfig, clientConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    RedisClusterConfiguration redisConfiguration() {
        RedisClusterConfiguration  redisClusterConfiguration = new RedisClusterConfiguration(clusterProperties.getNodes());
        redisClusterConfiguration.setMaxRedirects(clusterProperties.getMaxRedirects());
        return redisClusterConfiguration;
    }





    @Bean
    public ReactiveRedisOperations<String, Object> reactiveRedisTemplate( LettuceConnectionFactory  factory) {
        StringRedisSerializer keySerializer = new StringRedisSerializer();
        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<Object> valueSerializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(
                Object.class);
        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<String> valueSerializer1 = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(
                String.class);
        RedisSerializationContext.RedisSerializationContextBuilder<String, Object> builder = RedisSerializationContext
                .newSerializationContext(keySerializer);
        RedisSerializationContext<String, Object> context = builder.key(valueSerializer1).value(valueSerializer).build();
        return new ReactiveRedisTemplate<>(factory, context);
    }
```

RedisClusterConfig :

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.redis.cluster")
public class RedisClusterConfig {

    /*
    * spring.redis.cluster.nodes[0] = 127.0.0.1:7379 spring.redis.cluster.nodes[1]
    * = 127.0.0.1:7380 ...
     */
    private List<String> nodes;

    /**
     * spring.redis.cluster.max-redirects=3
     */
    private int maxRedirects;

    /**
     * Get initial collection of known
     * cluster nodes in format
     * {@code host:port}.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public List<String> getNodes() {
        return nodes;
    }

    public void setNodes(List<String> nodes) {
        this.nodes = nodes;
    }

    public int getMaxRedirects() {
        return maxRedirects;
    }

    public void setMaxRedirects(int maxRedirects) {
        this.maxRedirects = maxRedirects;
    }

}
```

my yml file :

```
spring:
   redis:
    cluster:
      nodes[0] : "192.168.53.73:7000"
      nodes[1] : "192.168.53.73:7001"
      nodes[2] : "192.168.53.73:7002"
      nodes[3] : "192.168.53.73:7003"
      nodes[4] : "192.168.53.73:7004"
      nodes[5] : "192.168.53.73:7005"
      enabled: true
      max-redirects: 3
```

exception :

```
31-05-2023 10:56:32.914 [reactor-http-nio-4] INFO  i.c.sadad.avatarapi.services.Aspects.redisReactiveCacheGet - Evaluated Redis cacheKey: material
31-05-2023 10:56:43.605 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-8-4] WARN  i.l.c.c.t.DefaultClusterTopologyRefresh.lambda$openConnections$12 - Unable to connect to [10.10.25.7/<unresolved>:7002]: connection timed out: /10.10.25.7:7002
31-05-2023 10:56:43.605 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-8-7] WARN  i.l.c.c.t.DefaultClusterTopologyRefresh.lambda$openConnections$12 - Unable to connect to [10.10.25.2/<unresolved>:7003]: connection timed out: /10.10.25.2:7003
31-05-2023 10:56:43.605 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-8-8] WARN  i.l.c.c.t.DefaultClusterTopologyRefresh.lambda$openConnections$12 - Unable to connect to [10.10.25.3/<unresolved>:7004]: connection timed out: /10.10.25.3:7004
31-05-2023 10:56:43.605 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-8-3] WARN  i.l.c.c.t.DefaultClusterTopologyRefresh.lambda$openConnections$12 - Unable to connect to [10.10.25.6/<unresolved>:7000]: connection timed out: /10.10.25.6:7000
31-05-2023 10:56:43.605 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-8-2] WARN  i.l.c.c.t.DefaultClusterTopologyRefresh.lambda$openConnections$12 - Unable to connect to [10.10.25.5/<unresolved>:7001]: connection timed out: /10.10.25.5:7001
31-05-2023 10:56:43.605 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-8-1] WARN  i.l.c.c.t.DefaultClusterTopologyRefresh.lambda$openConnections$12 - Unable to connect to [10.10.25.4/<unresolved>:7005]: connection timed out: /10.10.25.4:7005
```